# NodeUnit - Using wildcards

Tags: json, node.js, nodeunit

I'm making automated acceptance tests for a JSON REST API, using NodeUnit. I've a test for creating resources, which returns the created resource (according to [this](http://jsonapi.org/) specification) and I would like to compare the result from the API with my own JSON object, like:

```
test.deepEqual(response.body.data, {
    type: 'Employees',
    id: '1',
    attributes: { Name: 'Marten', Birthdate: '1995/05/25' },
    relationships: {
        Speciality: {
            links: {
                self: testBase.baseUrl + 'Employees/1/relationships/Speciality',
                related: testBase.baseUrl + 'Employees/1/Speciality'
            }
        }
    },
    links: { self: testBase.baseUrl + 'Employees/1' }
});
```

Just one problem: since the tests (NodeUnit) are asynchronously, the Id of the created resource could be anything. In this case '1', but it could be '2' or even '95'. So, is there a possibility for using a wildcard instead of a numeric value?